# Ajax call or js to update a cart price

Tags: java, javascript, e-commerce

I am building a cart in Java and would like to give users the ability to update the quantity and see the new price instantly. I am using *BigDecimal* on the back-end for complete accuracy, but the ajax call introduces a slight delay. It isn't much but I could make the update instant by sending the update to the server and just updating the price in Javascript before it even returns. The speed would be wonderful but it comes at the expense of rounding errors being presented to the user.

Now the back-end computed price would be the one shown on the payment page so that would be accurate at least but is the speed worth the risk of a bad value showing in the cart in an eCommerce system?

Comment: What am I missing?  Why not fix the rounding errors?

Comment: Because the rounding error is a result of the internal representation of decimal numbers in javascript. There is the chance you could end up with something like 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004. This is a trivial example but enough of them multiplied can result in unwanted values.

Comment: You just do `var cents = Math.round(total*100); var displayDollars = Math.floor(cents / 100); var displayCents = cents % 100;`  That will work for a max error less than a half cent.  You can calculate your max error, but for the kind of math you're likely to do on an ecommerce site, it's probably going to be down in the billionths of cents.  If you're really paranoid, google for a JavaScript bigdecimal library and see how they handle it.   Do you honestly think JavaScript would survive as a language if there wasn't some way to handle these kinds of use cases?

Comment: I once saw code ages ago that had floats and doubles constantly converted back and forth. That'll make a person jumpy when it comes to these errors. Say, you should make your comment an answer. I would accept that.

Answer (score 1):

If you let the math for one  second aside, the following should answer your question: 
The webpage, your client received is nothing more than a view. If you want to "display" changes immediately to your customer, you could do the math in JS. No roundtrip to the server needed. Think of oyur system under load: 100 000 people add and delete items on their shopping card. The result is unnecessary background noise on your server to calculate the new sum. What a waste of ressources.

Calculate and display the result via JS for the client and do the *real* math on the server, when the order is done.